# POST doesn't pass variable

Tags: php, post, curl, get

Here is my code. After I click the button to go to the "playlist.php" file, the variable isn't carried over like it should in the "post" command. Help?

EDIT: this is the code in the document that sends the variable.

```
if(empty($name) || empty($email)){
        echo '<h1>Please fill out all fields.</h1>';

    }else{

        $dup = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM sets WHERE name='".$_POST['name']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($dup) >0){
            echo '<h1>Username Already Used.</h1>';
        }
        else{

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sets VALUES ('','$name','$email')");     
            if($sql){

                 $to = $email; 
                 $email_subject = "You've created a playlist!";
                 $email_body = "Thanks for signing up! ".
                 " Here are the details you used to sign up with:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email"; 

                 $headers = "From: email@email.com"; 
                 $headers .= "Reply-To: email@email.com";

                 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

                 echo '<form action="playlist.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <p class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Visit my Playlist!</button></p>
                 </form>';

            }
            else{
                echo '<h1>Error in Registration.</h1>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not checking `$_POST['name']` anywhere

Comment: this is the document that sends the variable, not the one that receives the variable.

Comment: So what do you mean by `sends`? Only mail is being send in this code

Comment: What does your `html` form code look like?

Answer (score 2):

At least one error I can see in your code is this line:

```
echo '<form action="playlist.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <p class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Visit my Playlist!</button></p>
                 </form>';
```

You cannot have the `<?php echo $name; ?>` inside the string literal of an `echo` statement.
Use this instead:

```
echo '<form action="playlist.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $name . '">
                    <p class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Visit my Playlist!</button></p>
                 </form>';
```